# Send chat message via Office Communicator Server (OCS) from Java application

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip, office-communicator

I am looking for some API to connect to OCS server and send a chat message. I can understand Microsoft uses a modified version of SIP protocol, usually referred to as SIPE.

Pidgin has a plugin to communicate with OCS using the below plugin

```
http://sipe.sourceforge.net/
```

But I could not find any Java API to use it directly. Has someone done this before?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple API lib for this:

http://jsip.sourceforge.net/

It has not been updated for ages, but should be enough for you to get started.

Good luck!